# CMD command - output to file - not working well

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I have an EXE file that I run with this syntax:

```
[program.exe] [specific_test] [TRUE|FALSE] [iteration_number]
```

<sup>note: **details are not important here...**</sup>

On each iteration, the file prints a line: `iteration #i`, and when I run the test, all the output is presented on the CMD window.

Command:

```
C:\temp>FuzzNDIS.exe fuzzmethod true 1000
```

End of output:

> [image]

---

As you may see, all 1000 iterations ran (0-999). But, when I only add this to the command:

```
C:\temp>FuzzNDIS.exe fuzzmethod true 1000 > C:/Temp/NDISFuzzer/logs/log.txt
```

And try to get the exact same output in a file, it will always cut the X last iterations:

[image]

---

- And the issue is consistent:
  If I want 100 iterations, it will get until ~64, for 10k iteration there will be 9996 prints, for 7000 it's 6960, but never the amount I asked for.
  It always misses the end for some reason.

**Obs.:** When the output is not to a file, but to the CMD window, all works great!

- for all the suggestions to redirect the error buffer - the thing is that the lines are not errors and should be printed, without directing it to a file, all printed on the screen and all passes so it is not the issue in this case and those solutions didn't help me.
- is there any other way to output easily everything that comes out on the CMD window? or maybe something external to access the window and copy its content?
- List item

Comment: Run the following in PowerShell: `some.exe arg1 arg2 arg3 | Tee-Object -FilePath "${env:USERPROFILE}\output.txt"`

Comment: It may be that some of the iterations are displayed as errors, in that case they are not on buffer 1, but the error stream (buffer 2). typing your command `... > file 2>&1` should do the trick.

Comment: @megamorf my powershell wont recognize Tee-Object command, which is weird since I checked online and it should be an internal command and not something external to download. am I right?

Comment: @LPChip I tried but the results are the same. :\

Comment: Yes, Tee-Object has been in PowerShell for ages, see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/tee-object?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Use: `command | clip` and past the output in one  text editor where is possible to see any non printable character..

Comment: (0) You say “details are not important here...”  How do you know?  (1) You say that the last (third) command-line argument is “iteration_number”, but it looks like it is really number of iterations.  This detail might be unimportant, but the discrepancy is confusing.  (2) Is this a professionally developed, commercial software product, or is it amateur / home-grown?  (2a) Does anybody else use the program?  Do they have the same problem you do?  (2b) Do you have access to the source code and/or the developer?  (3) Please show us consistent information.  Your second (last) screenshot … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  suggests that each `oid` line is followed by a `method` line, but your first example suggests that the output *ends* with an `oid` line.  Also, is there a blank line after each `method` line (before each `oid` line) or not?  Again, this detail might be unimportant, but the fact that you show us inconsistent data is troubling.  (4) Please run a bunch of tests with output to files, and then tell us the sizes of the files (e.g., as reported by the `dir` command). … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.